Is there a way to intercept token call in react-oidc
I'm currently working on an authentication system in a React application using the @axa-fr/react-oidc library. Previously, our setup worked well with a public client, but we've recently had to transition to a private client. This change requires us to include the client secret in our OidcConfiguration. However, since this configuration resides on the front end, exposing the client secret is obviously not secure or viable.
Here is our current OidcConfiguration:
const oidcConfiguration: OidcConfiguration = {
    client_id: env.oidcClientId,
    redirect_uri: window.location.origin + "/authentication/callback",
    silent_redirect_uri: window.location.origin + "/authentication/silent-callback",
    scope: "openid profile",
    authority: env.oidcAuthority,
};

To mitigate the issue, I implemented an endpoint on the backend server that attaches the client secret and returns the JWT. The challenge I'm facing now is that the @axa-fr/react-oidc library relies on the OIDC discovery document from the authority to automatically determine the token endpoint and related endpoints.
Is there a way to intercept the token endpoint call and direct it to my custom backend endpoint? Any advice or guidance on how to approach this would be greatly appreciated, as I'm currently at an impasse.
Thank you in advance!
To resolve the issue of securely handling the client secret, I attempted to manually configure the OidcConfiguration by adding an authority_configuration object. In this object, I tried specifying my custom token endpoint, among other OIDC endpoints:
export const oidcConfiguration: OidcConfiguration = {
  client_id: process.env.REACT_APP_OIDC_CLIENT_ID,
  redirect_uri: process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URL + "/authentication/callback",
  silent_redirect_uri: process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URL + "/authentication/silent-callback",
  scope: "openid profile",
  authority: process.env.REACT_APP_OIDC_AUTHORITY, 
  authority_configuration: {
    authorization_endpoint: 'https://my-custom-auth.com/authorize',
    token_endpoint: 'https://my-custom-auth.com/token',
    userinfo_endpoint: 'https://my-custom-auth.com/userinfo',
    end_session_endpoint: 'https://my-custom-auth.com/logout',
    revocation_endpoint: 'https://my-custom-auth.com/revoke',
    check_session_iframe: 'https://my-custom-auth.com/checksession',
    issuer: 'https://my-custom-auth.com/',
  },
};


I expected this configuration to allow the library to use my custom endpoints, thereby enabling me to securely handle the client secret through the backend without exposing it on the frontend.
However, this approach didn't seem to work as expected. The @axa-fr/react-oidc library still defaults to using the endpoints defined in the OIDC discovery document provided by the authority, instead of the custom endpoints I specified in the authority_configuration. This leaves me unable to effectively redirect the token endpoint call to my backend service.
I'm looking for a way to override or intercept these default endpoint calls so that I can use my custom backend endpoint for token exchange. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
